# Adding multiple filters to a single video

Tags: ios, swift, gpuimage

I am trying to add filters repeatedly on a saved video with GPUImage2 but as I apply second filter it gives below error:

> Warning: tried to add target beyond target's input capacity --> Pipeline.swift: addTarget(_:atTargetIndex:): 43

and the selected filter doesn't applies. I tried removing targets from filter and movieInput before applying any new filter but nothing works.

Here is my code:

```
var renderView = RenderView()
var movieInput:MovieInput!
var selectedFilter:ImageProcessingOperation!

func startVideoWithFilter(filter:ImageProcessingOperation){
    let bundleURL = Bundle.main.resourceURL!
    let movieURL = URL(string:"fileName.mp4", relativeTo:bundleURL)!

    filter.removeAllTargets()
    selectedFilter.removeAllTargets()

    if movieInput != nil{
        movieInput.removeAllTargets()
    }

    do {
        movieInput = try MovieInput(asset: AVAsset(url: movieURL), playAtActualSpeed: true, loop: true)
        movieInput.addTarget(filter)
        filter.addTarget(renderView)
        movieInput.runBenchmark = true
        movieInput.start()
    } catch {
        print("Couldn't process movie with error: \(error)")
    }

}
```

Comment: why you are using it with asset url in `MovieInput` ? as you are using local video to apply filter.

Answer (score 0):

```
let vignetteFilter = Vignette()
let toonFilter = ToonFilter()

do {
    movieInput = try MovieInput(asset: AVAsset(url: movieURL), playAtActualSpeed: true, loop: true)
    movieInput --> vignetteFilter --> toonFilter --> renderView
    movieInput.runBenchmark = true
    movieInput.start()
} catch {
    print("Couldn't process movie with error: \(error)")
}
```